# centering float

Tags: css, css-float

I want the picture plus the gray background to be centered.

The body's style is set like this:

```
body {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:1000px;}
```

The div for the picture is this:

```
{width:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;float:right;}
```

The image style is this:

```
{border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px;}
```

If I removed the float the gray border around the image will fill all the page. and I do not want to specify a certain width for the border because some images are big and some are small.

I need help centering the image!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Add `text-align: center` to `#chpheader`, and remove `float: right`.
- Add `display: inline-block` to `<div style="text-align:center;background-color:#DCDEDD;margin-top:20px;border-radius: 20px;">`.
- If you need IE6/7 compatibility, instead add `display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1`.

You should not be using inline styles.

Comment: I did all what you said and still the same thing !

Comment: Did you remove `float: right`? I kinda forgot to add that important part to my initial answer :)

Answer (score 0):

image style should be `margin:0px auto` not just `margin: 0px`